# I need these 3 ID's to work for me in SQL

Tags: java, database, sqlite, netbeans

The Title of my project is Media Advertisements DB. I want these to be displayed in a Java GUI in a pretty accordingly and neat way. Like there are options where the user can view those different tables, but also to display them all at but when I display those, it is disaccordingly... How to make the structure better?

Here are the tables I have made:

[image]

Comment: "Any help..?" is not a proper question; you need to be specific. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for help with that.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a contract is limited to a single customer then you could have a column in the contract table to reference the customer.

Pic I take it is the customer's picture, if so then there would be no need to reference this from the contract as the contract referencing the customer would be sufficient to get the Pic.

So for example if the following were used to create and populate the tables (DROP tables just included for testing) :-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS customer_tb;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS customer_tb (
    cus_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
    company TEXT, 
    firstname TEXT, 
    middlename TEXT, 
    lastname TEXT, 
    gender TEXT, 
    dob TEXT, 
    dateregistered TEXT, 
    contactno  TEXT, 
    emailaddress TEXT, 
    description TEXT, 
    pic INTEGER
);
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS mediaadv_tb;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mediaadv_tb (
    med_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
    mtype TEXT, 
    title TEXT, 
    dateadded TEXT, 
    previewimg BLOB, 
    filepath TEXT
);
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS contracts_tb;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS contracts_tb (
    contract_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
    status TEXT, 
    priority TEXT, 
    dateadded TEXT, 
    dateexpiration TEXT, 
    amountpaid REAL, 
    arearofcoverage TEXT, 
    customer_reference INTEGER REFERENCES customer_tb (cus_id)
);

-- Populate customers_tb
INSERT INTO  customer_tb VALUES ("1","ACME","Fred","Tom","Smith","Male","1964-03-26","2018-0101","+54-1234 5678","fred@acme.email.com","Fred is called fred","1");
INSERT INTO customer_tb VALUES ("2","EMCA","Bert","Alan","Johns","Male","1976-10-11","2018-02-01","+54-4321 9876","bert@bertmail.com","competitive","2");
INSERT INTO customer_tb VALUES ("3","Quite Contrary Trading","Mary","Mary","QC","Female","2000-04-07","2017-02-15","+54-7654-3210","maryqc@easymail.com","Likes gardening","3");

--Populate mediaadv_tb
INSERT INTO mediaadv_tb VALUES ("1","type1","Freds photo","2018-01-01","X'00000001'","C:/images/customers/pic001");
INSERT INTO mediaadv_tb VALUES ("2","type2","Bertss photo","2018-02-01","X'00000002'","C:/images/customers/pic002");
INSERT INTO mediaadv_tb VALUES ("3","type3","Marys photo","2018-02-14","X'00000003'","C:/images/customers/pic003");

--Populate contracts_tb
INSERT INTO contracts_tb VALUES (null,"finalisation","Fast","2017-06-19","2018-05-01","123.45","Here and there","3");
INSERT INTO contracts_tb VALUES (null,"pending","medium","2017-06-19","2018-05-01","457.89","Over there","2");
INSERT INTO contracts_tb VALUES (null,"negotiating","TBA","2018-01-01","2020-01-01","567.65","Overall","3");
INSERT INTO contracts_tb VALUES (null,"building","Super fast","2017-11-01","2018-06-01","333.21","London","1");
```

The resultant tables would be :-

[image]

[image]

[image]

The following query based upon the contracts table joined with the customers table and then the customers table joined to the mediaadv table :-

```
SELECT contract_id, 
    dateexpiration,
    status,
    priority, 
    firstname||' '||middlename||' '||lastname AS fullname, 
    company, 
    title, 
    previewimg 
FROM contracts_tb 
    JOIN customer_tb ON customer_reference = customer_tb.cus_id 
    JOIN mediaadv_tb ON mediaadv_tb.med_id = pic
ORDER BY dateexpiration ASC
```

Would result in :-

[image]

As it stands the cutsomer_tb and mediaadv_tb could be merged into a single table. However I didn't do this as it's not at all clear what use will be made of the table.

Comment: Oh my god! You actually did what i want to happen but can't get a vision of! Thanks! So in all of those three, which do you think should be the main parent table? I know either one of those should be a parent table.

Comment: Hey sir MikeT? To explain things further, status is composed of two (active or inactive), then mediatype could be: video, audio, flyers. 
Somehow, can you help me distinguish which should be the appropriate relationship between those 3 tables?

Comment: The main use for customer_table is to display customer's details, then media_table where one media would refer to one customer, then contracts_table displays all the transactions and the media_id and customer_id included in one contract. I'm thinking about the inactive contracts it's so neat when it is sorted by date expiration but only sorting via status would sort it accordingly...